# Issues with TextView and raw files

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, togglebutton

I'm coding an Android app that deals with raw text files. What I've noticed is that when using a Toggle Button, the textview displays some odd characters before the actual text of the file.  The picture below shows the characters I'm talking about. I want to know how to get rid of these characters as they can't appear in the final version of the app. Does anybody know what the issue would be?
 [image: The strange characters are boxed in red before the capital "D"]
[image]

The code that handles the toggle button is as follows:

```
ELswitch = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    ELswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked==true)
            {
                InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sunday_compline_latin);
                System.out.println(R.raw.sunday_compline_english);
                try {

                    text.setText(inputStreamToString(iFile));
                    text.setFocusable(false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sunday_compline_english);
                try {

                    text.setText(inputStreamToString(iFile));
                    text.setFocusable(false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The code runs fine and there doesn't seem to be anything about it that would be changing the text file as these characters don't appear in the original file. Additionally, I have a similar activity that doesn't use a toggle button and these characters only appear in this instance (with the toggle button). Is there a problem with the code? Does anyone have a suggestion?

Here's my inputStreamToString:

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(is);
    String strLine = null;
    while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
    }

    dataIO.close();
    is.close();

    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Do you need to use `openRawResource()`? This is the Byte Order Mark of UTF16(Little Endian) Text.

Comment: I suppose I don't but I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what you mean. Is there another way of reading from the raw resource file without using openRawResource? Or are you saying that the text files are in a bad format?

Comment: Which `inputStreamToString()` method are you using? i can't find it in Android SDK

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) of the `readLine()` method you used, follow the advice there and give feedback if it helped, or not.

Comment: The two unwanted characters have been replaced with two white diamonds with questions marks in them. It's a step in the right direction. I got rid of the diamonds by checking the text files. They were saved as Unicode and not ANSI. Changing them to ANSI fixed the problem. Thanks so much for your help!